# How Ruby/Rails decide when a Thread.current should be killed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I have heard this comments many times and understand the importance to kill a thread local before it gets reused:

> "Not cleaning up thread-locals might be an issue if your framework reuses threads".

In the following example, it is straightforward to tell when the thread local should be killed:

```
def do_with_current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user] = self.current_user
    begin
        yield
    ensure
        Thread.current[:current_user] = nil
    end      
end
```

In Rails debugger, I see a `Thread.current` stay alive after a few actions and loading models/routes (there is no thread local killing mechanism in place in the app). My question is how Ruby/Rails determines when to kill a thread local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is Rails doesn't determine when to kill thread local variables so you might end up with a serious mess if them if you don't have code like this to automatically remove them. I try to stay away from them whenever possible, but there are cases when they cannot be avoided.

In those situations, avoid leaving any trace of them behind. Clutter in the thread local variable department can cause huge headaches as those objects cannot be garbage collected.

Your code can be simplified, too:

```
def do_with_current_user
  Thread.current[:current_user] = self.current_user

  yield
ensure
  Thread.current[:current_user] = nil
end
```

You may want to introduce a wrapper as well:

```
def current_user_local
  Thread.current[:current_user] || self.current_user
end
```

That way in your code it's not obvious you're using thread-local variables and if you ever change your mind about how that information is stored, you don't have to go and track down instances of `Thread.current` and replace them.

Comment: RequestStore(https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) gem is used in our app to manage thread local. This gem wraps Thread.current and kills a thread after use. The problem is that it kills a thread before it gets to `model` loading which replies on thread local to load right workflow. That's why we come back to use Thread.current only once as well as RequestStore and has to kill Thread.current after use. Thanks for the comments.